# Installing an Outlook addin for Local Machine registry hive

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

I am using regasm.exe to install my Outlook plugin on the end users' machines. However, I noticed that in a terminal server environment, my addin wouldn't load for all users. I found out that the addin registry keys were being created under the current user hive and not the local machine hive.

Is there something i can add to my plugin which will enable regasm to create/delete the keys under HKLM as well as current user when a user installs or uninstalls the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by digging through my sample NetOffice Outlook addin project!

All you need are a couple of public static methods with the `ComRegisterFunctionAttribute` and `ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute`  attributes. Regasm.exe will automatically execute the code in these methods when your plugin is installed or uninstalled.

See below for the code I am using which is slightly modified from the template to support the HKLM registry key. Add these methods to your Outlook addin class.

Alek's answer can be used if you wish to handle these manually.

```
    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            // add codebase value
            Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(OutlookPlugin));
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\InprocServer32\\1.0.0.0");
            key.SetValue("CodeBase", thisAssembly.CodeBase);
            key.Close();

            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\InprocServer32");
            key.SetValue("CodeBase", thisAssembly.CodeBase);
            key.Close();

            // add bypass key
            // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948461
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("Interface\\{000C0601-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
            string defaultValue = key.GetValue("") as string;
            if (null == defaultValue)
                key.SetValue("", "Office .NET Framework Lockback Bypass Key");
            key.Close();

            // add outlook addin key
            Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable");
            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(_addinOfficeRegistryKey + _prodId);
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(_addinOfficeRegistryKey + _prodId, true);
            rk.SetValue("LoadBehavior", Convert.ToInt32(3));
            rk.SetValue("FriendlyName", _addinFriendlyName);
            rk.SetValue("Description", _addinDescription);
            rk.Close();

            //Add registry key under HKLM
            RegistryKey regHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;

            regHKLM = regHKLM.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\" + _prodId);

            regHKLM.SetValue("Friendly Name", _addinFriendlyName);
            regHKLM.SetValue("Description", _addinDescription);
            regHKLM.SetValue("LoadBehavior", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string details = string.Format("{1}{1}Details:{1}{1}{0}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine);
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured." + details, "Register " + _prodId, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"CLSID\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable", false);
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(_addinOfficeRegistryKey + _prodId, false);

            Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\" + _prodId);
        }
        catch (System.Exception throwedException)
        {
            string details = string.Format("{1}{1}Details:{1}{1}{0}", throwedException.Message, Environment.NewLine);
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured." + details, "Unregister " + _prodId, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had other, but similar issues with `regasm.exe`, as I wanted to avoid the UAC in windows when registering the AddIn, so I wrote a com registrar by myself, which does the proper registry keys to register the com addin.

You would have to change this code accordingly to have the registry keys in those places were you want them, and obviously have similar code to rollback those changes on uninstalling your add-in

```
class ComAddinRegistrar
{
    private static string CLSID = "{CLSID}";
    private static string ASSEMBLY_NAME = "Outlook.Addin";
    private static string ASSEMBLY_DLL = "Outlook.Addin.dll";
    private static string VERSION = "1.0.0.0";
    private static string IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY = "{CATEGORY_ID}";

    public static void RegisterAddin(bool is64Bit)
    {
        // Get path of dll:
        var apPpath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        apPpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(apPpath);
        var path = ASSEMBLY_DLL;
        var dllPath = Path.Combine(apPpath, path);

        // Com registration
        RegistryKey rkey;
        if (is64Bit)
            rkey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)
                .OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Classes", true);
        else
            rkey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32)
                .OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Classes", true);

        var comAssemblyNameKey = rkey.CreateSubKey(ASSEMBLY_NAME); //HKCU/Software/Classes/Outlook.Addin
        comAssemblyNameKey.SetValue("", ASSEMBLY_NAME); // default value
        var clsidAssemblyNameComKey = comAssemblyNameKey.CreateSubKey("CLSID"); //HKCU/Software/Classes/Outlook.Addin/{CLSID}
        clsidAssemblyNameComKey.SetValue("", CLSID); // default value
        RegistryKey clsidComKey;
        if (is64Bit)
            clsidComKey = rkey.CreateSubKey("CLSID").CreateSubKey(CLSID); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}
        else
            clsidComKey = rkey.CreateSubKey("Wow6432Node").CreateSubKey("CLSID").CreateSubKey(CLSID); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}
        clsidComKey.SetValue("", ASSEMBLY_NAME); // default value
        var inProcServerKey = clsidComKey.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32"); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}\InProcServer32
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("", "mscoree.dll");
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Both");
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("Class", "Outlook.Addin.Addin");
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("Assembly", $"Outlook.Addin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("RuntimeVersion", "v4.0.30319");
        inProcServerKey.SetValue("CodeBase", dllPath);

        var versionKey = inProcServerKey.CreateSubKey(VERSION); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}\InProcServer32\1.0.0.0
        versionKey.SetValue("Class", "Outlook.Addin.Addin");
        versionKey.SetValue("Assembly", $"Outlook.Addin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        versionKey.SetValue("RuntimeVersion", "v4.0.30319");
        versionKey.SetValue("CodeBase", dllPath);

        var progIdKey = clsidComKey.CreateSubKey("ProgId"); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}\ ProgId
        progIdKey.SetValue("", ASSEMBLY_NAME);

        var implementedCategoryKey = clsidComKey.CreateSubKey("ImplementedCategories"); //HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID}\ImplementedCategories
        implementedCategoryKey.CreateSubKey(IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY);

        //AddIn registration
        //HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Addin
        var okey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
                                       .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
                                       .OpenSubKey("Office")
                                       .OpenSubKey("Outlook")
                                       .OpenSubKey("Addins", true);
        var addinKey = okey.CreateSubKey(ASSEMBLY_NAME);
        addinKey.SetValue("FileName", dllPath);
        addinKey.SetValue("FriendlyName", "My addin");
        addinKey.SetValue("Description", "some addin description");
        addinKey.SetValue("LoadBehavior", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try!